# Javascript Hidden Button

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, .net

I have a Javascript that works and its purpose is to hide a link/button for XYZ period of time.

Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function showNextButton() {
       document.getElementById("nextbutton").style.visibility = "visible";
    }
    // adjust this as needed, 1 sec = 1000
    setTimeout("showNextButton()", 30000); 
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<div id="nextbutton" style="visibility: hidden">
    <a href="nextpage.html">Continue</a>
</div>
```

The script works great but I would like to know how I can show a disabled link/button prior to having the main button appear after 30 seconds.

For Example Button: (This is a disabled useless button just letting visitor know they have to wait 30 seconds to Continue.)
[Disabled for 30 Seconds]

Then thirty seconds passes but and have that replaced with:
[Continue]

Can someone please tell me what I have to do to modify this script to do this?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### [Demo Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/W25U4gfrev9qmDeJv6mT?p=preview)

**Description**

This code will countdown from 30 to 0 then switch to the continue link.  You could change it or ask for something else.

---

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="wait" style="display: block">
      <a id='countdown-link'>30 seconds</a>
    </div>
    <div id="nextbutton" style="display: none">
      <a href="nextpage.html">Continue</a>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

---

**JS**

```
//29 because we have already waited 1 second before
var counter = 29;
//function that gets called every second
function showNextButton() {
  //if we are at 0 it has been 30 seconds
  if(counter == 0)
  {
    //show the continue link
    document.getElementById("nextbutton").style.display = "block";
    //hide the wait text
    document.getElementById("wait").style.display = "none";
    //disable the timer so we don't keep calling this function after 30 seconds
    clearInterval(myTimer);
  }
  else
  {
    //every second change the text
    document.getElementById("countdown-link").innerHTML = counter + ' seconds';
    //lower the timer counter by 1 since it has been 1 second
    counter--;
  }
}

//setup timer to call showNextButton every 1 second
var myTimer = setInterval("showNextButton()",1000);
```

---

**Verified Browsers**

- Chrome
- Firefox
- Safari
- IE8-IE11 (can't test below IE8 because of plunker, but this javascript should work back to IE6)

---

### [Using disabled button method](http://plnkr.co/edit/2eLd4oExGxPwreCLzGFg?p=preview)

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <input id='next-button' type='button' disabled onclick="window.location='nextpage.html'" value='30 seconds'/>
  </body>

</html>
```

**JS**

```
var counter = 29;
function showNextButton() {
  if(counter == 0)
  {
    document.getElementById("next-button").disabled = false;
    document.getElementById("next-button").value = 'Continue';
    clearInterval(myTimer);
  }
  else
  {
    document.getElementById("next-button").value = counter + ' seconds';
    counter--;
  }
}

var myTimer = setInterval("showNextButton()",1000);
```

Comment: You rock dude love this snippet even better then what I was thinking. Now could you tell me is this cross browser friendly with IE and others?

Comment: @FrankG. this should work with any browser, if not let me know and i'll verify support.  I added a comment to every javascript line i hope this helps in understanding how it works.  Understand that anyone who understands javascript could just bypass the 30 second wait time.  The download sites that require 30 second wait times use AJAX calls with server side timers.  But this will at least give you a starting point.

Comment: Would it be difficult for the avg Joe to figure out how to by pass it? Yes that is very helpful. I'm not to worried about people possibly modifying the time because what it is used for is to just delay someone on a page. No purchasing timer or nothing like that. And to figure it out in Ajax I bet would be a nightmare for me :( lol Great Job thank you very much!!!

Comment: @FrankG. yeah you'd have to understand javascript, debugging javascript, and more (above average joe stuff)...it wouldn't be worth it unless this code is protecting something a hacker would want to violate link downloading from one of the many file hosting websites...if it is just to delay the user even I would likely just wait the 30 seconds.  Also for production quality code I wouldn't use links but buttons or bootstrap styling for divs to look like buttons, but this code works and sometimes that's enough if you need more from me please ask.

Comment: Thank you for the verify! Does it not work in IE 7? Although people really need to start up grading browsers I run in to a lot of people who are still using IE 7 unfortunately!

Comment: @FrankG. no it works in IE7 i just didn't bother testing in it, so it isn't `verified` instead it is purely speculative.

Comment: Okay well great job and thank you very much it is perfect!! :)

Answer (score 0):

Make another element visible when you hide the nextbutton, and then hide it when you enable the nextbutton.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function showNextButton() {
        document.getElementById("nextbutton").style.visibility = "visible";
        document.getElementById("disabledbutton").style.visibility = "hidden";
    }
    document.getElementById("disabledbutton").style.visibility = "visible";
    // adjust this as needed, 1 sec = 1000
    setTimeout("showNextButton()", 30000); 
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<button href="11.html" id="nextbutton" disabled>Disabled for 30 seconds</button>


<script type="text/javascript">
    function showNextButton() {
        document.getElementById("nextbutton").disabled = false;
        document.getElementById("nextbutton").innerHTML = "Continue";
    }

    // adjust this as needed, 1 sec = 1000
    setTimeout(function(){showNextButton()},30000);
</script>
```

Comment: I tested this in jfiddle and it didn't work correctly http://jsfiddle.net/e2xvu/1/ Thank you!

Comment: here is the working jsfiddle for this http://jsfiddle.net/e2xvu/16/ answer, just some configuration needed because of the way jsfiddle handles `onload` vs in `<head>`